# Get Tooltip of button in a GridView using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview which fills dynamically from database having buttons (Edit , Delete ) too.Each button has a tooltip. I want to get the tooltip of individual button on mouse hover in a row. how would I do this.

Comment: Add title attribute to buttons.

Comment: all button same message or deferent message?

Comment: If buttons have different text than bind title with column name from database.

Comment: actually, i want to access the tooltip value of button through jquery. tooltip renders to title on page load , if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(".trow").mouseover(function () {
                        Console.log($(this).find(":button").attr('title'));
                    });
        });
```

**trow** is class name of row and above function will return tooltip of each button in current row.